# Cannot get response to work with ansible script

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, python-winshell

I have a simple ansible script where I'm attempting to disable the radios.  I would like to use win-shell (powershell) to do this but it expects a response but I can't figure out how to make it work:

I attempted all kinds of things but this is the latest:

```
-name: Disable wifi and blutooth
  win-sh:
    A '' | Disable-NetAdapter -Name "*"
```

When I run Disable-NetAdapter in powershell it prompts for a confirm yes, yes to all etc. A selects yes to all.

Can someone help me out with this.  I used "expects" but had no luck with that either.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
-name: Disable wifi and blutooth
  win-sh:
    Disable-NetAdapter -Name "*" -Confirm:$false
```